# android - onSaveInstanceState callback how to save a SpannableString

Tags: android, string, configuration, parcelable, spannablestring

I have a string thats HTML formatted and saved as a SpannableString.  On a config change etc onSaveInstanceState is called prior and then onRestoreInstanceState to restore states etc.  How can i save and restore a spannableString ... all i see is methods to save a string but  not spannable items:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("mystring", aString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like i have to take advantage of two methods to ge this done...

```
public static String toHtml (Spanned text)
```

and

```
public static Spanned fromHtml (String source)
```

so call toHTML when saving it as a string and then fromHTML when restoring it.